# CORS for XHR in IE10

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer, cors

I am getting these errors when someone attempts to open my app in IE. I get a popup asking to Allow Blocked Content, and when this is clicked everything works fine. Is there anyway I can go about enabling CORS to bypass clicking Allow Blocked Content?

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/info?f=json required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). 
EDDM_API.html

SEC7120: Origin file: not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 
EDDM_API.html

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
EDDM_API.html

SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://static.arcgis.com/attribution/World_Street_Map?f=json required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). 
EDDM_API.html
```

Searching the web I found this bit of code, just unaware of where to put it in my script, or if it will even solve my problem.

```
// Script running on http://eddmapi-dev.usps.gov/eddmapi/eddm_api.html
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onerror = _handleError;
    xhr.onload = _handleLoad;
    xhr.open("GET", "http://eddmapi-dev.usps.gov/eddmapi/eddm_api.html", true);
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you think this is a GIS question?

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot a webapp I made with the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

Comment: I don't think the problem is anything to do with that particular API (and is hence off-topic), but I'm  not worried enough to do anything about it. Perhaps you might like to look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57546/cors-issue-arcgis-10-1-iis-cross-origin-resource-sharing and check this isn't the same issue.

Comment: Does your web server use IIS or Apache?

Comment: @BradHards assuming that CLJ's answer is correct, that would give a reason why this is GIS-specific, ie it depends on a feature of the ArcGIS JS API

Comment: Version of IE? Screenshot of message?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with IE10. Could you check the web site behavior with other Browser?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Blocked content is not related to using the esri services. Try creating a simple site that just creates a map with basemap and set [esriConfig.defaults.io.corsDetection](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/inside_defaults.html) = false and then explicitly adding any coors enabled servers into esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers as suggested by CLJ. This will get rid of the error XMLHttpRequest and should hopefully reveal that the issue is related to another aspect of your site

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify your enabled servers:

```
esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("serverapi.arcgisonline.com");
esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("services.arcgisonline.com");
esri.config.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("static.arcgis.com");
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to configure the webserver to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Depending on whether you use IIS, Apache, or one of the other ones out there, reconfiguring the app isn't too difficult. Here's a link to how to enable CORS for your application: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: He can't enable coors http://services.arcgisonline.com as this isn't his server it's ESRI's server. There has been an 'ideas' open for this for a long time, please upvote it http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bvtBAAQ